# in the past days

Tags: meaning, adjectives

1. I am talking about the events in the **recent** days.
2. I am talking about the events in the **past** days.

In which case the 'days' might not include yesterday?

In other words in which case the events might have ended
the day before yesterday (or even two days before yesterday)?

Comment: The idiomatic standard here is ***in recent days*** (where the article is *never* included). Your version #2 is very unusual in that exact form, but commonly occurs as ***in*** (more often ***over***) ***the past few days*** (or some more specific amount than "few"). Yesterday would naturally be included by default in all cases, but only exact context will give any indication as to whether the events have already finished, or are still ongoing.